# Unable to click on suggested results using casperjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, casperjs

I have a modal window with user input fields. When I type any name in the field, suggestion drop down appears (like in google search page suggestion). I am unable to click on the 1st suggestion below is the screen shot of the field with suggestion

[image: Text field with suggestions]

And here is the html snippet

```
<div class="selectize-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-isolate-scope multi">
<div class="selectize-input items not-full ng-valid ng-pristine has-options">
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" tabindex=""
           style="width: 4px; opacity: 1; position: relative; left: 0px;">
</div>
<div class="selectize-dropdown ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-isolate-scope multi"
     style="display: none; width: 448px; top: 100px; left: 0px; visibility: visible;">
    <div class="selectize-dropdown-content">
        <div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="djoky">
            <span class="highlight">djo</span>
            ky
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The test case scenario is:
1. Click on the field
2. Enter a name and suggestion appears
3. Click on the suggestion

Here is my CasperJS code

```
this.sendKeys(x(".//*[@id='group-tab']/div[3]/div/div/div[1]"), 'djoky');
    this.echo('adding member name');
    this.wait(3000);
    this.click(x(".//*[@id='group-tab']/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/span"));
    this.echo('Clicking the name from the member suggested');
});
```

till sendKeys it is working but unable to click on suggested name field

Comment: try to add z-index css property to suggestion div or element

Comment: since i am beginner, could you explain it with the example?

Comment: try this css code .selectize-dropdown-content .option{z-index:9999999}

Comment: Try to click on the `.option` div and not the inner span

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it might help you

```
casper.then(function (){
    this.click(x(".//*[@id='group-tab']/div[3]/div/div/div[1]"));
    this.echo('Click 1');
    this.sendKeys(x(".//*[@id='group-tab']/div[3]/div/div/div[1]"), 'dj');
    this.echo('typing');
    this.wait(3000);
    this.click(x(".//*[@id='group-tab']/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div"), 'djoky', {keepFocus: true});
    this.echo('Click from the list');
    this.wait(4000);       
});
```